# What's the tiebreaker for top tags?

Tags: support, tags, profile-page

My profile on [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/44520/glorfindel) shows [tolkien-languages] as my top tag. It's one of the tags on my [highest scoring question there](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/177218/44520), but I'm wondering why this tag is chosen instead of the other two. [tolkien-legendarium] has more questions; if the order would be alphabetical, [gollum] would be shown instead. Or is this just random (read: depending on an undefined sort order in SQL)? It's not the oldest tag either, as on [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/4495/glorfindel) the newest of the three tags, [processor] is shown as top tag.

[image]

Comment: [tolkien-languages] was created [6 years ago](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/tolkien-languages/info), while [tolkien-legendarium] was created [5 years ago](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/tolkiens-legendarium/info). Maybe it's that the oldest tag (first created) appears first?

Comment: Nice try, thanks, but I found a counterexample.

Comment: Would there be any deleted questions in play here?

Comment: @Luuklag I have one deleted answer on Hardware Recommendations, on a Roomba'd question, but it has a different tag.

Comment: My best guess, based on virtually everything else: it's just random. Decided once on first hit, then put into permanent cache.